# .NET Container w/ Menu on Left Side

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, controls

I was wondering the easiest way (open source control / .NET control) to set up a windows form with a menu on the left that changes the panel displayed on the right.

Here are two example screen shots of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the one [in this codeproject post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/DockContainer.aspx) for a project and it works fine, I didn't do strange things with it, but it certainly can do what you are asking.